# Responsive CSS Div Width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In CSS, I have defined 3 breakpoints 360px, 660px, 800px. There are multiple `<div>` tags on page with just text link in it. 1 `<div>` block having 1 `<a>`.

For 360px breakpoint, I am going with 100% width for each `<div>`. But for other 2 breakpoints I want to have normal width of `<div>` (normal width based on text length). How to achieve this for 660px and 800px breakpoints as these are getting to 100% width as well. I want these 2 to take natural width.

Comment: At 360px, you want `div` to be full-width, and if greater than 360px you want it to be sized to content? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mzdzsh4f/ ?

Answer (score 6):

`<div>` is a block level element which means by default it is always going to take 100% of its container's width. so, instead of 3 breakpoints as you mentioned, you can just mention 1 breakpoint, lets say 800px, and set the `<div>`'s `width` to be `max-content`

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
  div {
    width: max-content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just change all div's display "block" and "inline-block" with breakpoints

like this:-

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .example{
     display:block;
  }
 }


 @media only screen and (min-width: 660px) {
  .example{
    display: inline-block;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you want it to behave, what is your layout goal.
If all you want to achieve is neutral width of divs, the:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

will be enough, but it will also cause div collapsing into one line, if its width allows that. 
If you want them to stay the way they are, I would actually recommend using flex display on container with those div like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyuenan/13/)

But after all, it depends what you want to get exactly, and you problem description is not enough to determine that.